# Salesforce Database.query - Object and Where Clause Variable

Tags: apex, soql, community

I am having an issue with the database.Query. I keep getting a I think error on of my object variable doesn't exist or my where clause is incorrect. This is what I tried

```
 String strObjectName = soOrder.Record_Name__c; 
 String strName = soOrder.Record_id__c; 



 1.) 

  List<sObject> lstOrder = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM strObjectName WHERE Name = :strName');

2.) 

 string strQuery = 'Select Id  From ' + strObjectName + ' where Name =:  ' + strName;


List<sObject> lstOrder = Database.query(strQuery);
```

I am getting an error on the where clause in which when the database.Query fires it wants single quotes around it.

Comment: What are the errors? Could you include them in the question please?

Comment: Added the error. It wants single quotes around my where clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Object name does not support [bind operator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm); so you would need to do a concatenation for 1st scenario:

```
List<sObject> lstOrder = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM ' + strObjectName + ' WHERE Name = :strName');
```

And in your second approach, you do not need a bind operator as you're performing a String concatenation (Use `escapeSingleQuotes` to prevent [SOQL injection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm)):

```
String strQuery = 'SELECT Id  FROM ' + 
    strObjectName + 
    ' WHERE Name = ' + 
    String.escapeSingleQuotes(strName);
```

Comment: Did you try this query ? AFAIK, binding object name in dynamic SOQL query gives unexpected token exception.

Comment: @VijayGanji This is quite common scenario with dynamic SOQL, bind operator simply resolves the variable with its corresponding value.

Comment: I did a quick test in anonymous window and its giving me a unexpected token exception

Comment: @VijayGanji Ah you're right!, was not quite sure hence also had added second approach :)

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways of doing this and it depends on the requirement.

When you are comparing a field's value with the variable, you will have to use the bind expression i.e. `:`, and when using bind expression, mention the variable in the query itself.

If you don't want to use the variable in SOQL, then you will have to prepare your SOQL using string concatenation, but using this approach, you will have to handle the SOQL injection as well.

Also, you cannot bind object name using bind expression, you can find further help about Dynamic SOQL at [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) link

Hence the simplest approach I can think of is using below query

```
string strQuery = 'Select Id  From ' + strObjectName + ' where Name =:strName';
List<sObject> lstOrder = Database.query(strQuery);
```